# Why PHP Script Tag

Tags: php

There are 5 tags available to start a php code block. I've read about Script Tags:

```
<script language="php">
... code
</script>
```

Definition: Script tags were introduced so that HTML editors that were able to ignore JavaScript but were unable to cope with the standard PHP tags could also
ignore PHP code.

Can anybody explain about the definition?

Comment: What isn't clear about that definition?

Comment: "HTML editors that were able to ignore JavaScript but were unable to cope with the standard PHP tags could also ignore PHP code." 
When and where should I use?

Answer (score 2):

There are four different pairs of opening and closing tags which can be used in PHP. one of those

```
<script language="php"> </script>
```

**Defention :** This is used to differentiate from Javascript code but HTML editors are unable to cope up even with standard PHP tag

**Note:** In PHP 7 `<script language="php"><script>` Tags are removed.

`<?php ?>` is the most commonly used and recommended to use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Laksmi.
If script tags considered deprecated and use of it is strongly discouraged then why the script tags are good for?

Answer (score 0):

These tags were created for IDE and text editors long time ago. At that time, IDE and text editors did not know PHP, so PHP had to pretend to be javascript or similar.

You do not need to use them now. You may use `<?php`, the current "default" tag. the `<script>` tag was removed from PHP 7